# I want to know what does this sentence mean "Netflix Faces Challengers in Its Push to Expand Globally"?

Tags: sentence-meaning

Here I want to know what is push according to this sentence.Can anyone explain what this sentence mean?

Comment: Please tell us what parts (phrases or words) you're having trouble with.  Have you looked up all the words in a dictionary?  Please quote the dictionary and tell us what about the definitions you don't understand.

Comment: Here know the meaning of push but according to the sentence what is meant by push here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's somewhere between 2.1 and 2.3 [here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/push)

> 2.1 (Of an army) advance over territory:
>   '*the guerrillas have pushed south to within 100 miles of the capital*'
>
> 2.3 (push for) Demand persistently:
>   '*the council continued to push for the better management of water resources*'

I'd characterize it here as "a deliberate and explicit effort to achieve a goal."